# Iphone Bluetooth Connection To Non-IOS Device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, bluetooth

I've been looking into adding a feature to support input from a blue tooth device for my iphone application. From what I've found in my research, most people point to using the `GameKit FrameWork`. The issue here, is that it only seems to support Iphone -> Iphone connections.

Most of the documentation or questions I saw were between 1-2 years old, perhaps something else has been released?

Comment: Is this going to the AppStore? If so, you better forget that. If not, you'll have hard time implementing it (but it's definitely possible).

Comment: This is an in house application.

Comment: good, in this case you don't have to worry about Apple's restrictions. Anyways, I'm sad to tell you but it's hard to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [Core Bluetooth Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011295) by Apple?
It's working for iOS 5+